# How to find packages, which are not compatible with PDF 1.7?

Tags: luatex, packages, pdf, incompatibility

LuaLatex Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021) prints a warning `(pdf inclusion): PDF inclusion: found PDF version '1.7', but at most version '1.5' allowed` and I want to change the PDF version to 1.7 now.

How can I find out which packages are not compatible with PDF 1.7 before I [change to PDF 1.7 for the whole document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638194/how-to-generate-pdf-1-7-output-with-lualatex)?

Comment: I know none, I would simply use pdf 1.7 or pd 2.0.

Comment: I think the issue isn't latex packages but whether at the time the rest of the infrastructure, viewers, convertors etc could cope, but 1.7 has been out for a long time now..